# LocalSystem account not recongizing FQDN as intranet, causing open file security warning when deploying from SCCM 2007

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, sccm, sccm-2007

I have spent the last two days reading and trying every solution online, but I cannot figure out the best way to approach this.

We use SCCM to deploy packages and it uses the localsystem account to install the software when run as administrator. This for some reason now causes the open file security prompt.

When running the advertisement as user rights, this prompt does not occur as the GPO policy for users and computer has the domain in the Intranet zone.

I know that the localsystem account does not use these keys and uses the .default key and the only way I have been able to get this to work without getting the prompt is to put the domain in zonemap key for .Default.

Now I don't know if this is the way to fix this or if this causes a security issue. Does anyone have any idea?

And this is only happening on windows 7 machines, not windows XP.

EDIT: example when launching would be \server.na.company.com\d$\setup.bat calling msi to install .